# LPCM 2.0 stereo audio data operation

Tags: audio, digital

I've search it for a long time on Google and Wiki and I don't have much progress. There are someone who can help me.I'll be very appreciate。 I want to operate the left and right channels in lpcm. For example: I want to intercept the right channel data, left the left channel data to replace the original right channel data. What IC do I need to use? What is the specific data format of lpcm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pcm data is usually interleaved. So every even index [0,2,4...] is left and the odd indexes [1,3,5...] are right samples. So go through and replace the odd samples.

I didn't see the question about the IC!  I can't answer unless you the actual format of the LPCM!  There are many different formats, but the most popular is I2S.  There are lots of different DSPs and MCUs that can do those formats, too.  Take a look at anything by Analog Devices (Blackfin) or Texas Instruments.

Comment: hi,@c.fogelklou thanks for your answer .So what IC or MCU or DSP should I need?

Comment: I edited my answer.  Anything with a focus on media (Bluetooth, automotive telematics, etc.)  should have a block in it that can be configured for the most common LPCM formats.